# Ruby Date.strptime difficulties when parsing 13/Nov/11

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date, strptime

When parsing a Jira Custom Field containing a date (e.g. 13/Nov/11) I started with this:

```
elsif custom.customfieldId == "customfield_10282"
@agenda_item.planned_release_date      =  custom.values.to_s
```

But the database stores it as 11/13/0011. So I got clever and used this:

```
elsif custom.customfieldId == "customfield_10282"
@agenda_item.planned_release_date      =  Date.strptime(custom.values, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

And now I get:

private method `sub!' called for ["15/Nov/11"]:Jira4R::V2::ArrayOf_xsd_string
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:429:in`_strptime_i'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:401:in `scan'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:401:in`_strptime_i'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:601:in `_strptime'
[truncated the rest of the stack]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
p Date.strptime('13/Nov/11', "%d/%b/%y")
```

Your problems:

- `` `%Y `` is the year with 4 digits (`2011`). Use `%y`
- `%m` is the month in digits (`11`). Use `%b` instead (`Nov`)

Comment: ARG! Arg I say... thanks. Should have been more attentive to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

If I properly understand your issue, try to use this:

```
Date.strptime('13/Nov/11', "%d/%b/%y")  # => 2011-11-13
```

You have abbreviated month name and there for you should use `b` format directive. Beside this because your year contains only two last numbers, use `y` directive.